# Find the $\frac{d}{dx}$ of $g(x)=\int_{2x}^{3x} \frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}du$

Tags: calculus

First I split the integral

$$\int_{2x}^{0} f(u)du+\int_{0}^{3x}f(u)du$$
Then differentiate with respect to x
$$\frac{d}{du}\left[\int_{2x}^{0}f(u)du+ \int_{0}^{3x}f(u)du\right]\frac{dx}{du}$$
In my notes after diff. with respect to x  I  have
$$f'(x)=\frac{4x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
$$f'(2x)=\frac{8x}{(2x^2+1)^2}$$
$$f'(3x)=\frac{12x}{(3x^2+1)^2}$$
Then for an answer I get 
$$g'(x)=\frac{-2(4x^2-1)}{4x^2+1}+\frac{3(9x^2-1}{9x^2+1}$$

And I can't understand how I arrived at that answer.

Comment: The fourth line does not make sense: $u$ is nothing but a dummy variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F(u)$ be a function such that $F'(u)=f(u)$ with
$$
f(u)=\frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}.
$$
The [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) tells you that
$$
g(x)=F(3x)-F(2x).
$$
Now by the chain rule you get
$$
g'(x)=3\cdot F'(3x)-2F'(2x)=3f(3x)-2f(2x)=\frac{3(9x^2-1)}{9x^2+1}-\frac{2(4x^2-1)}{4x^2+1}.
$$

---

Alternatively, you could apply directly the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: So after plugging in I get $\frac{27x^2-3}{27x^2+3}-\frac{8x^2-2}{8x^2+2}$ Then how do i arrive at the answer?

Comment: You did the wrong "plugging in". $3f(3x)-2f(2x)=3\cdot\frac{(3x)^2-1}{(3x^2)^2+1}-2\cdot\frac{(2x)^2-1}{(2x^2)^2+1}={\color{red}{\frac{3(9x^2-1)}{9x^2+1}-\frac{2(4x^2-1)}{4x^2+1}}}$ **is** your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(u) \, du=f(b(x)) \frac{d}{dx}(b(x))-f(a(x)) \frac{d}{dx}(a(x))$$
In your case $a(x)=2x, b(x)=3x$ and $f(u)=\frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}$. You don't need the derivatives of $f$ that you have computed.

Comment: so I sub in 3x for u to get $3x^2$?

Comment: @EricBrown Actually $f(3x)=\frac{(3x)^2-1}{(3x)^2+1}$.

Comment: so after plugging in I get $\frac{9x^2-1}{9x^2+1}(3)-\frac{4x^2-1}{4x^2+1}(2)$. Then I multiply the two fractions to get $$\frac{27x^2-3}{27x^3+3}-\frac{8x^2-2}{8x^2+2}$$

Comment: @EricBrown Yes that's correct.

Comment: Do I still need to integrate the two fractions?

Answer (score 1):

$$I(u)=\int\frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}\mathrm du$$
$$I(u)=\int\frac{u^2+1}{u^2+1}\mathrm du-2\int\frac{\mathrm du}{u^2+1}$$
$$I(u)=u-2\int\frac{\mathrm du}{u^2+1}$$
Using the substitution $\tan t=u$, we arrive at
$$I(u)=u-2\arctan u$$
And from $g(x)=I(3x)-I(2x)$, 
$$g(x)=x+\arctan2x-\arctan3x$$
Hence
$$g'(x)=1+\frac2{1+4x^2}-\frac3{1+9x^2}$$